# Is getchar() equivalent to scanf("%c") and putchar() equivalent to printf("%c")?

Tags: c, scanf, getchar, putchar

Is `a = getchar()` equivalent to `scanf("%c",&a);`?

Is `putchar(a)` equivalent to `printf("%c",a);` where `a` is a `char` variable?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507082/getc-vs-getchar-vs-scanf-for-reading-a-character-from-stdin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking yes they are the same.

But they are not in a few nitpicky ways.  The function `getchar` is typed to return `int` and not `char`.  This is done so that `getchar` can both all possible `char` values and additionally error codes.

So while the following happily compiles in most compilers you are essentially truncating away an error message

```
char c = getchar();
```

The function `scanf`, though, allows you to use a `char` type directly and separates out the error code into the return value.

Comment: Not error messages (as in, plural), "only" EOF. But otherwise, this is correct. It should also be said that getchar() is much more efficient than scanf(), because the library doesn't have to parse the format string (and the linker doesn't have to link in the large block of code that is scanf()).

Answer (score 1):

They do the same thing here. However, if you know you are just doing characters then `getchar` and `putchar` will be more efficient, since the `printf` and `scanf` variants will have to parse the string each time to determine how to process your request. Plus, they may be called in a lower level library meaning you may not have to have the `printf`/`scanf` linked if they are not needed elsewhere.