# getc Vs getchar Vs Scanf for reading a character from stdin

Tags: c, character, scanf, getchar, getc

Of the below three functions:

getc
getchar &
scanf

which is the best one for reading a character from stdin and why?

Are there any known disadvantages or limitations for any of these functions which makes one better than the other?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you simply want to read a single character from stdin, then `getchar()` is the appropriate choice.  If you have more complicated requirements, then `getchar()` won't be sufficient.

- `getc()` allows you to read from a different stream (say, one opened with `fopen()`);
- `scanf()` allows you to read more than just a single character at a time.

The most common error when using `getchar()` is to try and use a `char` variable to store the result.  You need to use an `int` variable, since the range of values `getchar()` returns is "a value in the range of `unsigned char`, plus the single negative value `EOF`".  A `char` variable doesn't have sufficient range for this, which can mean that you can confuse a completely valid character return with `EOF`.  The same applies to `getc()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In scanf if I give only %c, then I should be able to read only one character right?

Comment: Yes, but it is overkill for that purpose.

Comment: Seriously overkill.  On many platforms, getchar() is a macro that quickly returns a character (with a buffered stream), or uses fread() to get a character.  With scanf(), there's a lot of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 6):

[from Beej's Guide to C Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/getc.html)

> All of these functions in one way or another, read a single character
>   from the console or from a FILE. The differences are fairly minor, and
>   here are the descriptions:
>
> getc() returns a character from the specified FILE. From a usage
>   standpoint, it's equivalent to the same fgetc() call, and fgetc() is a
>   little more common to see. Only the implementation of the two
>   functions differs.
>
> fgetc() returns a character from the specified FILE. From a usage
>   standpoint, it's equivalent to the same getc() call, except that
>   fgetc() is a little more common to see. Only the implementation of the
>   two functions differs.
>
> Yes, I cheated and used cut-n-paste to do that last paragraph.
>
> getchar() returns a character from stdin. In fact, it's the same as
>   calling getc(stdin).