# Dynamic string allocation in c

Tags: c

The function I am having a problem with is the one I created below, DynamicString.
The function is meant to create a string of variable size.

```
void DynamicString(char **txt)
{
    int i;
    int n = 0; //number of characters
    char c;
    *txt = (char *)malloc(1);//one byte of memory for the terminator
    (*txt)[0] = '0'; // termination charcter is the first point
    char *tmp = NULL; //temporary pointer

    scanf("%c", &c);
    while(c != '\n')//while true input
    {

        tmp = (char*)malloc(n+2);//allocates memory for incoming charcter and termination point
        for (i=0; i < n; ++i)//doesn't copy over an empty list
        {tmp[i] = (*txt)[i];}

        tmp[n] = c; //inputs character in releveant position
        tmp[n+1] = '0'; //places term. point
        ++n;// incriments the number of charcters(not including 0
        scanf("%c", &c);
    }

    free(*txt);//frees old mem
    *txt = tmp;// txt points to tmp
    printf("\nThe entered string is : %s",*txt);


    return;
}

void Frequency(char *s, int *array)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)//counts the frequncies of each character
    {
        array[s[i]]++;
    }
    /* Print characters and their frequency */

    return;
}

int main()
{
    //int Freq[128] = {0};// frequency of characters
    char * string;
    DynamicString(&string);

    free(string);

    return 0;
}
```

If anyone can fix the code I have already created that would be very helpful. I know there might be a better algorithm but I just want to know what I'am doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Code looks strange, one of the problem is incorrect string termination symbol. It should be '\0', but not '0'.

Comment: I think all of your `'0'` characters should really be `'\0'`, which is quite different.  (I see two instances of `'0'` and one instance of `'\0'`)

Comment: No change unfortunately

Comment: The problem was that i was not copying over the tmp string in the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as others have pointed out, correct string end is `'\0'` which is a terminating `NUL` character.

Secondly, if the first character read happens to be the newline, the loop will never be executed. After you `free(*txt);` `*txt` points to `tmp` which is a `NULL`, so you cannot use `printf("\nThe entered string is : %s",*txt);` because you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer which is **undefined behaviour** in c.

Thirdly, you have a memory leak there because in the loop you are allocating memory to `tmp` using `malloc()`, which every time will give you a new memory address. This means in every cycle in the loop, `tmp` will have a new address and you lose the old address and you cannot free it anymore.

If you want to increase or decrease the size of the memory a pointer points to, use `realloc`. A very simple example how to use `realloc` would be like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int initalSize = 10;
    int increasedSize = 20;

    /*
     *  Because temp type is char, I left sizeof operator out. you can always write like
     *  char *sentence = malloc(initialSize * sizeof(*sentence)); or
     *  char *sentence = malloc(initialSize * sizeof(char));
     */
    char *sentence = malloc(initalSize);
    char *temp = NULL;

    /* 
     * Malloc can return a NULL pointer. You need to check sentence value before using it
     * elswhere in the code.
     */
    if (!sentence) {
      printf("Memory allocation failed for sentence\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Some code here...

    /*
     * Realloc can also return a NULL pointer. Need to use a temporary
     * pointer. In case realloc really returns NULL, and you don't use a temporary pointer and
     * use it like "sentence = realloc(sentence, increasedSize);", you will have a memory leak
     * because now sentence = NULL and you don't have a pointer that points to the old memory.
     *
     */
    temp = realloc(sentence, increasedSize);

    // Also need to check temporary pointer value.
    if (!temp) {
      printf("Allocating more memory to sentence failed\n");

      // One of the possible solutions. You can always use the value that you already have in sentence;
      free(sentence);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*
     * If everything was ok, you make sentence point to the same address in memory as temp was pointing.
     * What it means is that you give ownership of the memory temp points to the sentence.
     */
    sentence = temp;

    // Some code here...


    // No need for sentence anymore
    free(sentence);

    /*
     * It is always recomended to make unused pointers that you don't use anymore or if you have
     * freed them to point to NULL;
     * It makes sure that those pointers no longer point to the previous memory addresses. Remember that
     * free only frees the memory where sentence and temp pointed to.
     *
     * If you don't make them point to NULL, then sentence and temp would be called a dangling pointer.
     *
     */
    sentence = NULL;
    temp = NULL;

    // Some code here...

    return 0;
}
```

If you use Linux, it is always a good idea to check you code with a program called [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). It helps to detect memory leaks and memory errors.

In addition, to read a character from `stdin`, I would use `getchar()`. It is simpler, faster. A small information about it in a Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507082/getc-vs-getchar-vs-scanf-for-reading-a-character-from-stdin).

And the last note, if you use a function that returns nothing, you don't need to write `return` in the end of the function.