# How to read a stream of characters whose length is unknown from standard input in c

Tags: c, input, char, c-strings

I want to read a stream of characters from standard input whose length is unknown. I am trying to read character by character as

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    char ch;
    do 
    {
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        //do some comparison of ch
    }while(ch!='');
return 0;
}
```

Help me write the condition in while so that I can read input properly without entering into an infinite loop

Sample input:

```
abcdefghijklmnop
```

Comment: Do you mean how to *store* the unknown-size file you've read in memory? Because reading is kind of easy. Reading character-by-character is inefficient (and better done with `getchar`). If you don't want to impose size limits, I believe it would be best to make a linked list, allocate a chunk of memory, read until it's filled, then link a new chunk, till the file is done.

Comment: What do you consider as the end of your input stream? A carriage return? Something else?

Comment: @Amadan It's not about files

Comment: Streams. Same thing. (Actually not same thing, with a file you'd know the size, so what I describe would not be needed.) Unless your stream does not terminate; in that case, you should think hard what you consider the point when you are okay to stop listening. If you should always continue to listen, fork your process or tear off a thread.

Comment: If you must use `scanf`, you can check its return value - as it has 1 thing to match, it will return 1 on success and <1 on EOF or error. You can also use `feof(stdin)` and `ferror(stdin)` - as in

`while ( ( 0 == feof(stdin) ) && (0 == ferror(stdin) ) )`

Comment: Thanks @Sigve Kolbeinson . Your comment is what exactly I was looking for. For me return value would work I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a simplest form of solution will be this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    char ch;
    do 
    {
        ch = fgetc(stdin); 
        //do some comparison of ch
    }while( ch != EOF );

return 0;
}
```

But having said that, problem statement like below

> read a stream of characters from standard input whose length is
>   unknown

is a bit tricky. As per the program above is concerned you can probably stop it with a ctrl+d, EOF or run the binary with file redirection

> ```
> ./a.out < input.txt
> ```

in fact, the interpretation of standard input is what makes this question more meaningful.

Comment: I don't have the permission to use files and even I don't want to use them. And I cant use something like ctrl+d. will EOF work for stdin?

Comment: how will you end your program ?

Comment: Thanks @kkk, I tried combination of EOF and getchar(). it worked. Can you help me replicate the same functionality using scanf?

Comment: check this good read to decide on the replication case with scanf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640604/c-getchar-vs-scanf and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482634/is-getchar-equivalent-to-scanfc-a?rq=1

Comment: @BalakrishnaAvulapati This code is substantially correct except for the fact that ch **must** be declared as `int`.  The reason for this is that `EOF` is defined as –1 and `0xff` might be a valid byte.

Comment: @JeremyP I guess so but when you use getchar() , it implicitely reads it as integer. so the combination of EOF and getchar() worked for me. Thanks

Comment: @BalakrishnaAvulapati yes it does explicitly read it as an integer but ch is a char, so it immediately discards all but the least significant byte.  Trust me, you **must** declare ch as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Your escape character is wrong.
Your want to write everything on one line ? Then use '\n' to end your loop.

```
while (ch != '\n')
```

If you write character by character, use one to exit your sequence (for exemple '@')

```
while (ch != '@')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't have the permission to have my own exit character. I just have a stream of characters whose length is unknown and I want to read the characters one by one so that processing them for my scenario would be easier

Comment: When you say one by one, you mean you will write the first caracter, then enter, then second caracter, then enter ...? Or you write everything then enter but just read them one by one?
If it's the second use '\n'.